# How to make a board in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a board that lets users choose the number of rows and columns but I can't seem to put anything together!

For example if a user wants 3 rows and 3 columns I am trying to make it print out:

```
xxx
xxx
xxx
```

My code so far:

```
def main()
#ask for rows:
    print("Please choose the num of rows:")
    rows = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

#ask for columns:
    print("Please choose num of columns:")
    columns = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

#print rows:
    board = []
    
    for r in range(0, rows - 1):
      r = "x"
      print(r)

#print columns:
    for k in range(0, columns):
    board = board + ["x"]
   
    print(board)

main()
```

and this is what it outputs:

```
Please choose the number of rows:
Please enter a number: 3
Please choose the number of columns:
Please enter a number: 3

x
x
['x', 'x', 'x']
```

I feel really dumb for not being able to do something as basic as this but this was the best I was able to come up with! I sort of got it to print the number of rows / columns but i have no idea how to make it look "normal" or fill it in..

Can anyone more knowledgeable help me?

Thank you!

Comment: please past your code here. picture of text is usually a bad idea...

Comment: Oh ok! Sorry I'm new to the forum but I will edit the post! @Blag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a board in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903176/how-to-print-a-board-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the many ways to do it:

```
for x in range(row):
    print('x '*col)
```

For example, `row =3`, `col =3` then output :

```
x x x 
x x x 
x x x
```

---

**Alternatively**,

Create a list-

```
a=[]
for x in range(0, row):
    a.append(["x"] * col)
```

Then print it-

```
for row in a:
    print " ".join(row)
```

Comment: Whenever I use the print " ".join(rows) It says there is a syntax error!

Comment: Oh ignore that! I found what I was doing wrong! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @naraemee you are probably using python3. That is python 2 code.
Change that print statment to `print(" ".join(row))` for python 3.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me while creating the 2048 game board

```
# creating a board of 4 x 4 size
# initializes a list of lists with 4 rows and 4 columns
board = [ [0] * 4 ] * 4

# for printing the board
for row in board:
print(row)

# the result it produces
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
def main():
    print("Num of rows:")
    row = int(input())
    print("Num of Cols:")
    columns = int(input())
    print("Out:\n")

    for i in range(row): # iterate in rows
        print('x'*columns) # print 'x' columns times

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```